# Finding algorithm from encrypted code

Tags: security, encryption, sha

I have a word (can't provide it here) and its encrypted code:

```
1C6FC813B5D83F96BB5A4B62F421225E060AC2FCD3A2C4C31B029D92C96444AB6F943DE9B6D83764C8AC5DF743DF9A1FFAC14686B531BF2CDA551F561
```

I should find the encryption algorithm used for it. I tried `SHA-512` and generated me the same code as below but by including some zeroes.
I tried many online SHA generators and they all provided the same below encrypted code.

```
1c6fc813b5d83f960bb5a4b62f421225e060ac2fcd3a2c4c31b029d92c96444ab6f943de09b6d83764c8ac5df743df9a1ffac146860b05031bf2cd0a551f5601
```

Any idea about how some zeros are excluded?

Comment: SHA is not encryption; it is hashing.

Answer (score 1):

That are the same SHA-512 hashes displayed in hexadecimal with the following exception: In the top hash all bytes that in hex would have a leading `0` it was dropped, probably the binary to hexadecimal conversion was incorrect. Perhaps the format was `%x` instead of `%02x`.

Example:

```
printf("%x%x%x%x\n",         0x55, 0x02, 0x40, 0x66);
printf("%02x%02x%02x%02x\n", 0x55, 0x02, 0x40, 0x66);
```

Output:

> 5524066     <-- Notice the missing `0`
>   55024066